# Ajaxplorer Popup File Selector

Tags: javascript, pydio

I'm trying to use Ajaxplorer as a way to choose a file on the server and publish the file path in a form (basically linking the file to a db record). I want the behavior to work like CKFinder's popup functionality. I want the user to click a "choose file" button, Ajaxplorer appears in a new window, the user selects the file, and then the path to that file is sent back to the form and the popup is closed. I'm pretty sure that this is possible because the CKEditor plugin for Ajaxplorer seems to do just that.

I'm new to Ajaxsplorer, so I am just digging in. I was hoping that I could somehow pass a callback method to Ajaxplorer that would populate my field on select. However, it doesn't appear that I can do that based on the docs.

The other option looks like creating a plugin. I'm happy to do this, but the documentation is weak and it seems like others would have done this by now. So, before digging in to that for hours trying to learn the plugin system, I wanted to pose this question to the community.  Is there documentation or a plugin for Ajaxplorer that will allow me to send selected file info from a popup window back to my form?

Comment: I built a plugin to achieve this. I will post on GitHub and answer this question after the time limit is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by building a plugin.  I have attached the URL to the plugin in case others may want similar functionality.

[Ajaxplorer-Popup-Selector](https://github.com/scottharwell/Ajaxplorer-Popup-Selector)